# Has anyone ever gotten smited from a Werewolves game for reasons other than inactivity?

Tags: werewolv.es

Was anyone smited for a reason other than inactivity?

Comment: Why are you asking this? Do you have reason to believe it is possible? Did it happen to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. People who break the rules get smited. This includes copy-pasting results from night actions.